# Why initialize Set from dict.keys() is faster than using set.add()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

Code

```
total_exc_time = 0
for _ in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    set_a = set()
    dict_a = dict()
    add = set_a.add
    for index in range(1000000):
        dict_a[index] = index
        add(index)
    total_exc_time += ((time.time() - start) * 1000)

total_exc_time = 0
for _ in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    dict_a = dict()
    for index in range(1000000):
        dict_a[index] = index
    set_a = set(dict_a.keys())
    total_exc_time += ((time.time() - start) * 1000)
```

Result

```
332.3066234588623 ms
283.2982540130615 ms
```

isn't the time complexity for the first code is O(n) and later code is 2 times O(n)?

Comment: Function calls have overhead. Any overhead multiplied by ten million will becomes more noticeable. Idk if that's it, but it's a possibility.

Comment: "the time complexity for the first code is O(n) and later code is 2 times O(n)" - that's not how asymptotic complexity works.

Comment: sorry, I know the have the same O(n) but, the first code looks that it has less computation than the later code.

Comment: @bakumpai why does it look like that to you?

Comment: cause of dict.keys() ?

Comment: @bakumpai `dict.keys()` is a constant-time operation, it creates a *view* of the keys of a dict. It is also unnecessary, you can just do `set(dict_a)`

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. The heavy lifting here to calculate the key hash. In both, it happens twice: add to a dict and then add to set. Other procedures should be light. You can use debugger to show the C calls to verify.

In addition to function call overhead mentioned by Carcigenicate, memory management might also play a role. If the set knows the length, it could possibly avoid copying data over when the predefined space isn't enough.

Comment: doesn't dict.keys() populate a list? and it costs O(n)?

Comment: @bakumpai no it doesnt. Even if it *did* it could still be  faster to pass it to `set` than using `.add` in a loop. For starters, even if it did the same thing (not pre-allocating the entire set) it would *still* be faster because it is all done in compiled code, whereas your loop is at the interpreter, bytecode level, which will always be significantly slower

Comment: No. dict.keys() are views. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys

Comment: I didn't even think of the potential for reallocations/expansion. I don't think it can take that into consideration because the signature for `set` specifies an "iterable", which doesn't have a length, but it could do an attribute check or something regardless.

Comment: @Carcigenicate have to admit I didn't verify myself and it's hypothetical.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that doesn't mean that `set` couldn't implement various optimized paths for working with other built-in containers. Almost certainly it does. There is also `__length_hint__` which other built-in types take advantage of.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It does actually seem to take length into consideration, although I got lost a ways in. The initializer passes the iterable to `set_update_internal`, which does a call to `PyDict_GET_SIZE(other);` (`other` is the passed iterable), with a comment "Do one big resize at the start, rather than incrementally resizing as we insert new keys.".

Comment: @Carcigenicate yep, here's the link: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a85fefe71b3bf56b1b3e72e752e0f962c3b0b487/Objects/setobject.c#L868  so it seems to optimize for `dict` objects and other `set` objects. Not surprising since those are the hash-based containers. So actually, passing the key-view object makes this optimization fail, I believe. We could confirm by timing just the passing of `dict_a` instead of `dict_a.keys()`

Comment: it's the result, the first is passing dict_a

206.02624416351318 ms
226.28140449523926 ms

Comment: Ya, it looks like the dict keys object isn't considered to be a set or dictionary, so it falls through and uses the generic iterable handler.